# Why do I need web api to link between django and other js framworks

Tags: python, django

why do i need a web API to link between django and other JS frameworks for example django with angular?

And is it necessary to build a web API like (REST API) to link between back end and front end?

Comment: You should send data from server to client (Not neccessary to implement REST API philosophy).

Comment: @gachdavit How?

Comment: Write django views and return JsonResponse to client (You can do this from django).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is not JS library. It's a Python-based server framework. But your JS library communicates with a server via REST Api. So you need a web API to link between django and other JS frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Without more work than it is worth, the DJango and Angular frameworks probably cannot pass data between one and the other, since both run at the same logical level in the stack.

REST APIs are the generally accepted mechanism for communicating between SPAs implemented in different frameworks.